# Authentication Issue & Check Regex Issue Using Gatling

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

Want to Perform Load testing on Salesforce Platform. But it seems there is an error in authentication as well as regex part.
I am using **Gatling** testing tool & scala programming here.

If you guide me how to do load testing on salesforce that would be plus.

This is my code:

```js
package default

import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._


class requestUser extends Simulation { 

 val httpProtocol = http.baseURL("http://login.salesforce.com")

 val Test = exec(http("Login")
    .get("/")
    .basicAuth("abc@gmail.com", "Password+Token")
    .formParam("sessionId","*******")
    .formParam("orgId","***********")
                       )
    .exec(http("acc")
           .get("/path")
    .basicAuth("abc@gmail.com", "Password+Token")
    .check(status.is(200))
    **.check(css("#content"))
    .check(regex("""<div id ="header">Choose a Username</div>"""))
    .check(regex("""<td class = "datacell">Jaipur</td>"""))**
   )
    .exec(http("home")
      .post("/home/home.jsp")
      .formParam("Post", "Test from Gatling")
      .check(regex())
        )

 var scn = scenario("scn").exec(Test)

 setUp(
  scn.inject(rampUsers(1) over (10 seconds))
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)


}
```

Comment: Please share details about error?

Comment: <td class = "datacell">Jaipur</td>. exist(0) found nothing .

Comment: Error reported by XML parser: The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with '>'